# How to make a cross shaped kernel to apply morphological transformations in openCV using python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mathematical-morphology, image-morphology

I'm a beginner and I don't know how to make a cross shaped kernel in openCV using python? I want to make a 3x3 cross shaped kernel so I can apply morphological transformations to A1, and the kernel being B1.

Here is the picture of what A1 and B1 are.

[image: Here is the picture of what A1 and B1 are.]

This is what I have for the kernel but im getting a name error : name 'array' is not defined.

```
# Cross-shaped kernel (structuring element)
cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
kernel = array ([[0, 1, 0],
                [1, 1, 1],
                [0, 1, 0]], dtype = cv.uint8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array function is a part of the numpy. This is how you can create the kernel/array:

```
import numpy as np  

kernel = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                [1, 1, 1],
                [0, 1, 0]], dtype = np.uint8)
```